# perf report displays call graphs with unresolved kernel symbols

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, perf

I've gathered a perf trace of last branch record (LBR) samples:

```
$ sudo perf record -F 99 -a --call-graph lbr sleep 20
[ perf record: Woken up 41 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 16.786 MB perf.data (73420 samples) ]
```

Because I've installed the kernel debug symbols (via Ubuntu's linux-image-*xyz*-dbgsym package), I see kernel stack traces in the samples displayed by `perf script`:

```
Wt--1 48503 [034] 1429895.019844:     646342 cycles:
        ffffffff8d4e4cb5 update_nohz_stats+0x25 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d4e801b update_sd_lb_stats+0x25b (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d4e85b7 find_busiest_group+0x47 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d4e8bdf load_balance+0x15f (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d4e9f73 newidle_balance+0x2b3 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d4ea105 pick_next_task_fair+0x45 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8ded5214 __schedule+0x124 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8ded5833 schedule+0x33 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d547a89 futex_wait_queue_me+0xb9 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d548aa0 futex_wait+0x100 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d54b48f do_futex+0x35f (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d54bbef __x64_sys_futex+0x13f (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8d404207 do_syscall_64+0x57 (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
        ffffffff8e00008c entry_SYSCALL_64+0x7c (/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic)
            55c03ef7ad70 pthread_cond_timedwait@plt+0x0 (/home/xyz/myapp)
```

However, `perf report` is unable to resolve the same symbols. I get:

```
-   13.11%     0.00%  Wt--1            [unknown]                   [.] 0xffffffff8e00008c
   - 0xffffffff8e00008c
      - 12.17% 0xffffffff8d404207
         - 4.64% 0xffffffff8d54bbef
            - 2.89% 0xffffffff8d54b48f
               - 2.68% 0xffffffff8d548aa0
                  - 2.55% 0xffffffff8d547a89
                     - 2.52% 0xffffffff8ded5833
                        - 1.17% 0xffffffff8ded5214
                           - 1.01% 0xffffffff8d4ea105
                              - 0.96% 0xffffffff8d4e9f73
                                 - 0.54% 0xffffffff8d4e8bdf
                                      0.52% 0xffffffff8d4e85b7
                        - 0.65% 0xffffffff8ded54b9
                             0.65% 0xffffffff8d4d6a6a
```

Notice the stack above matches the frames in the `perf script` output. So, what's different between the way `perf report` and `perf script` resolve symbols?

Here's the verbose output from perf report:

```
$ perf report -v --stdio > /dev/null
build id event received for /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic: 05638de83d4b5ca5d11614484f9cd5525a8b2713
build id event received for /lib/modules/5.4.0-73-generic/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko: 18e6d209819f08e64e59fa19961c358f60a9d835
build id event received for /lib/modules/5.4.0-73-generic/kernel/drivers/intel/sgx/isgx.ko: 9a37f67aff8f86a47b837ea01e5c1f673b95527a
build id event received for /lib/modules/5.4.0-73-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb.ko: 497aa60f1ff31ae7690a99a8c5a151b3f22abd80
build id event received for /lib/modules/5.4.0-73-generic/kernel/drivers/ata/libahci.ko: 801c3ad29053c29e5078bdb2cbe0e7bda1e43ff0
build id event received for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so: 68f36706eb2e6eee4046c4fdca2a19540b2f6113
build id event received for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so: ce450eb01a5e5acc7ce7b8c2633b02cc1093339e
build id event received for [vdso]: 75f9eb38e31c3dc2fab6314c45b01b07bd6d047d
build id event received for /home/vsts-agent/bin.2.184.2/libcoreclr.so: 9b44902bfb6d8f9067767e551977f8306f9e8d94
build id event received for /usr/sbin/sshd: 6f0593060a136468805766d2931cbd91157951aa
build id event received for /usr/bin/htop: 27866c7878627b082ca43d3e147f3f867a32b53f
build id event received for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9: 8bbe057cadb725ac23aed0800c8f8cef05b207f1
Looking at the vmlinux_path (8 entries long)
Using /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic for symbols
symsrc__init: cannot get elf header.
Failed to open /home/xyz/mylib.so, continuing without symbols
[vdso] with build id 75f9eb38e31c3dc2fab6314c45b01b07bd6d047d not found, continuing without symbols
Failed to open [sep5], continuing without symbols
```

Notice that there is some user code for which I do not have symbols, so as expected both `perf script` and `perf report` are missing symbols there. This is the source of the symsrc__init error above.

Things I've already tried:

- Passing `--vmlinux`, `--kallsyms` and `--modules` parameters. This had no obvious effect, but sent me down a rabbit hole of rebuilding `perf` myself so it links against libbfd (Ubuntu's perf does not, and shells out to `addr2line` which makes it very slow in these cases).
- Inverting the display of call chains with `--inverted` or `--children`. This didn't change the fact that symbols were not resolved.
- Limiting the length of displayed stacks with `--max-stack=8` or similar. This significantly reduces the number of unresolved symbols showing up in the report, but I think it's just hiding the problem, because it prevents grouping samples from disjoint portions of a long callchain.

Comment: Where does Ubuntu's `linux-image-xyz-dbgsym` package install the separate debug-info files?  Is `perf report` looking *anywhere* for symbols?  (Perhaps `strace -e file -o perf-report.trace   perf report`  to see the filesystem system calls it attempted.)  With `--max-stack=8`, were there any specific addresses that resolved with that, but not with the default?  It would be weird if the same address resolved or not depending on *other* addresses.  Or do you just mean that it reduces the total size of the report, thus fewer unresolved symbols.

Comment: @PeterCordes it is indeed weird; I think it's a bug in perf. The unresolved 0xffffffff8e00008c at the top of the stack above is `entry_SYSCALL_64`, and when running perf report with `--max-stack=8` it is correctly resolved, along with its (first 8) callees that are all unresolved above. In both cases, perf finds and opens `/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-73-generic` for symbols.